# Convert RGBA to HEX

Tags: html, css, colors, hex, rgba

Given a css color value like:

```
 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86)
```

How do I convert that to a RGB hex value that takes the alpha component into account, assuming a white background?

Comment: RGBA perhaps, RGB can't take alpha into account unless you agree on some sort of steganography-like technique for inserting your data into it (and you need to have the bit-space to do that)

Comment: Nope, I mean RGB. Basically, what you would get when rendering the page, making a screenshot, and using a color picker to get the hex color value from the area that has the given rgba css color assigned to it.

Comment: Oh now I see what you're trying to do, sorry.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Since alpha value both attenuates the background color and the color value, something like this could do the trick:

```
function rgba2rgb(RGB_background, RGBA_color)
{
    var alpha = RGBA_color.a;

    return new Color(
        (1 - alpha) * RGB_background.r + alpha * RGBA_color.r,
        (1 - alpha) * RGB_background.g + alpha * RGBA_color.g,
        (1 - alpha) * RGB_background.b + alpha * RGBA_color.b
    );
}
```

(Try it interactively: https://marcodiiga.github.io/rgba-to-rgb-conversion)

Comment: That looks promising. Converting RGB to HEX is missing, but thats the easy part.

Comment: the link does not exist any more!

Comment: @gaitat Thank you for reporting it. Fixed it with a post on my blog.

Comment: Very cool. Could it please accept typed-in colors, as well as the current color picker?

Comment: @josinalvo Done, luckily the color picker I'm using supports it natively

Comment: Looks cool, but for some reason I cannot understand why it doesn't work for me. The way I'm trying to call it is `rgba2rgb('rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgba(255, 96, 92, 0.1)');`. And it gives me an error: "Color is not defined".

Comment: @johnc.j. Old comment but adding here for others. The function expects array or object values so that they can be accessed as RGBA_color.a, for example. In your comment, you are passing in strings.

Comment: I assume this code accounts for the white background with which the color blends. Does anyone know how to make this work for arbitrary background colors?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values are 0...1 per channel.
And assuming that the abbreviation in the method / function call in the question correspond to the arguments, the following should work.

```
A = 255 * 0.86
R = 255 * 0
G = 255 * 0
B = 255 * 0
```

*Note you may want to change how it rounds off here as it may give inaccuracies in colours.*

At this point, the values are in fact still floating point values, but casting them to a byte or a char (depending on language), should in theory work.

```
var _A = (byte)219.3
var _R = (byte)0
var _G = (byte)0
var _B = (byte)0
```

Now all you have to do is convert them to a hexadecimal string each, and concatenate them (ARGB) and put a nice little hash tag in front (#)

In C# you could do something akin to:

```
var hexString = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}", _A, _R, _G, _B);
```

Yielding a final result of something like:

```
#DB000000
```

Comment: That would still give me RGBA, just in another format. What I need is RGB, with the alpha applied to the individual RGB values.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert red,green and blue individually using `.toString(16)` and then combine the result in a case, if you just want to convert a rgb to hex... since you are searching to convert rgba to hex i thought it would be better to convert the rgba to rgb and then to hex as i did in the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/vZBa5/3/), which would also consider the `background-color` of the `parent` `div`.

Answer (score -2):

The rgba value you are having is:
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86)

First 0 stands for **RED**
Second 0 stands for **GREEN**
Third 0 stands for **BLUE**
and the last digit 0.86 stands for **alpha/opacity**

Here are some links for rgb to hex converter:

***http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm***
***http://www.rgbtohex.net/***
***http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php***

with you digits 0, 0, 0. The Hex Code will be

```
#000000
```

Following is the code for low opacity with a white background

***HTML***

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="childDiv">

    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
#parentDiv
{
height:100px;  /* The property of Child is Inherit */
width:100px;  /* The property of Child is Inherit*/
background-color:#ffffff;
}

#childDiv
{
height:inherit;
width:inherit;
background-color:#000000;
opacity:0.86;
filter:alpha(opacity="86");
}
```

Now the parent Div is the background with

```
#ffffff (White color)
```

Comment: None of the online converters you mentioned support alpha. The one I found doesn't appear to work.