# Change the shade of the color, with the reference to the original one

Tags: css, colors, background-color

```
<style>
    div.red {
        border-left: 5px solid rgb(255, 96, 92);
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
        width: 95%;
    }
</style>

<div class="red">
    <p>Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</p>

    <div class="red">
        <p>Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a base color (`rgb(255, 96, 92)`) and I need to incorporate it into the styling of divs, as a background.

The background of the divs should be something lighter then the base color, similar to

```
div.red {
    rgba(255, 96, 92, 0.25);
}
```

However, I cannot use

```
background: {rgba(255, 96, 92, 0.25);}
```

directly, because it changes the background color of the nested div.

Opacity is not suitable as well, because it changes the color of the text.

```
div.red {
    background: rgb(255, 96, 92);
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

Filters are not suitable for the same reason as the opacity: they affects the text.

Another option I'm aware of is the HUE color model. It is not suitable because I need to keep the reference to the base color.

`rgb(255, 96, 92)` is the same as `hsl(1, 100%, 68%)`. I can change 68 to 93 and it will give the desired visual effect. But now I cannot say, looking into my code, which color was the base one.

```
div.red {
    background: hsl(1, 100%, 93%);
}
```

The best way I am searching for is something like

```
div.red {
    background: rgba(255, 96, 92, 0.25);
    background-alpha-channel: separate; /* separate or merge,
                                           depending of what you need. */
}
```

Comment: It seems it could be better solved with JS. Use rgba for background, then JS should convert it to rgb. It seems I found the appropriate code, but for some reason I cannot understand how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21576659 (I already left comment there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pseudo element as a background layer and apply the filter there:

```css
div.red {
  border-left: 5px solid rgb(255, 96, 92);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.red:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: rgba(255, 96, 92);
  filter: brightness(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <p>Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</p>

  <div class="red">
    <p>Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to consider two background layer where the top one is a white color having alpha. Add more white will make the color more bright.

```css
div.red {
  border-left: 5px solid rgb(255, 96, 92);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 95%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5)),
    rgba(255, 96, 92)
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <p>Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</p>

  <div class="red">
    <p>Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @asobak I agree that solution is far from being perfect. However, there are no other ones for now.

Comment: @asobak *You should specify alpha value also in .red:before.*  --> read the question and you will understand why alpha will not work ... *and there is no clear indication of two different colors as OP is looking for.* --> the border and the background are having two different color, if this is not a clear indication then I have nothing to say.

Comment: @johnc.j. added another idea

Comment: The second version works perfect for me. Thanks a lot. Are there any reasons to have `position: relative` in the second version? (Looks like a typo).

Comment: @johnc.j. no, you can remove it, I simply kept it from the previous code