# R function for RGBA to HEX color conversion

Tags: r, hex, rgb, rgba

I am looking for some [function](/questions/tagged/function) in [r](/questions/tagged/r) which can convert a [rgba](/questions/tagged/rgba) color to Hex e.g. `rgba(240, 177, 76, 0.80)`. There are plethora of functions available from [rgb](/questions/tagged/rgb) to Hex conversion e.g. `plotrix::rgb.to.hex()` but not for RGBA.

Really appreciate any pointer.

Comment: Why not convert from RGBA to RGB (see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb)) and then convert from RGB to HEX (using plotrix)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic has been discussed [Convert RGBA to HEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576092/convert-rgba-to-hex/21576659#21576659)
however, I am not aware of an R package, that offers a ready to use function.

You can convert RGBA to RGB:

Since this depends on the background pixel's color ([Convert RGBA color to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb)) you have to define the background color. 
`color_RGBA` is your RGBA color and `background_RGB` is the background color.
You can take `col2rgb("white")` as `background_RGB` for example.

```
rgba2rgb <- function(background_RGB, color_RGBA){

  # get alpha
  alpha=color_RGBA[4]

  # get new color  
  new_col=matrix(c(
    (1 - alpha) * background_RGB[1] + alpha * color_RGBA[1],
    (1 - alpha) * background_RGB[2] + alpha * color_RGBA[2],
    (1 - alpha) * background_RGB[3] + alpha * color_RGBA[3]),
    nrow=3,ncol=1,dimnames=list(c("red","green","blue"))
  )
  return(new_col)
}
```

and then convert RGB to HEX:

```
rgb2hex <- function(x) rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], maxColorValue = 255)
```

Comment: What are background_RGB and color_RGBA in this function?

Comment: I edited my answer. RGBA to RGB conversion needs definition of the RGBA color and a background color

Answer (score 2):

I feel one possible solution is to add the alpha value (transparency) in the rgb definition of the color. You can do it with the `rgb()` function adding `alpha` parameter. If the color channels r, g, and b are between 0 and 255, you have to use `maxColorValue = 255` and express `alpha` also between 0 and 255, where 0 corresponds to complete transparency and 255 to totally opaque (full color)

Let me show the results for your case `rgba(240, 177, 76, 0.80)`:

```r
your_color <- rgb(240, 177, 76, alpha = 0.8 * 255, maxColorValue = 255)
# equivalent to
# your_color <- rgb(t(c(240, 177, 76)/ 255), alpha = 0.8)
your_color
#> [1] "#F0B14CCC"
```

I'll plot your color with others to get a better sense of the transparency applied.

- The full color

```r
full_color <- rgb(240, 177, 76, alpha = 255, maxColorValue = 255)
full_color
#> [1] "#F0B14CFF"
# equivalent to "#F0B14C"
```

- A half transparent color

```r
half_transparent <- rgb(t(c(240, 177, 76)/255), alpha = 0.5)
half_transparent 
#> [1] "#F0B14C80"

old_par <- par(mar = c(1, 0, 0.5 ,0) + 0.1, mgp = c(1, 0, 0))
barplot(rep(1, 3), names.arg = c("yours", "full", "half"), 
  col = c(your_color, full_color, half_transparent), axes = FALSE, cex.names = 1)
par(old_par)
```

[image]

Another question is which full RGB color is equivalent to a given color with a level on transparency. The answer by @capcoma helps here. Using

```r
background_color <- col2rgb("white")
background_color
#>       [,1]
#> red    255
#> green  255
#> blue   255

your_color_rgb <- col2rgb(your_color, alpha = T)
your_color_rgb
#>       [,1]
#> red    240
#> green  177
#> blue    76
#> alpha  204

alpha <- your_color_rgb[4, 1]/255
alpha
#> alpha 
#>   0.8

new_rgb <- (1-alpha) * background_color + alpha * your_color_rgb[-4, 1, drop = FALSE]
new_rgb_equivalent <- rgb(t(new_rgb), maxColorValue = 255)
new_rgb_equivalent
#> [1] "#F3C06F"
```

the expression for `new_rgb` is completely equivalent to the function `rgba2rgb()` by @capcoma. We can plot the equivalent rgb color ("eq") with the other 3 above

```r
old_par <- par(mar = c(1, 0, 0.5 ,0) + 0.1, mgp = c(1, 0, 0))
barplot(rep(1, 4), names.arg = c("yours", "full", "half", "eq"), 
  col = c(your_color, full_color, half_transparent, 
  new_rgb_equivalent), axes = FALSE, cex.names = 0.8)
par(old_par)
```

[image]

Column 1 and 4 should have the same color. Hope you find this useful.

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>